# Python shell "executing command, please wait for result"

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a code for a 5x5 tic-tac-toe game. it seemed to be working fine, but now in the middle of running the program, after entering a number nothing happens and the python shell says "Executing command. Please wait for result" at the top but nothing happens. I am not sure what the problem is as it seems to work fine before that happens. Any suggestions would be a great help.

```
from random import randint    
def displayBoard(board): #printing board with each list on new line
    for i in board:
        print(*i,sep='  ')
        
def checkIfLegal(number,board): 
    if number<=0 or number>25: #if number in correct range
        print("That cell does not exist")
        return False
    number=number-1 #to match indices
    row=int(number/5) 
    col=number
    if col>4:
        col=int(col%5)
    if board[row][col]=="X" or board[row][col]=="O": #checking if cell is occupied
        print("That cell is occupied")
        return False
    return True 

def updateBoard(number,board,symbol):
    number=number-1 
    row=int(number/5)
    col=number
    if col>4:
        col=int(col%5)
    board[row][col]=symbol #change cell to player symbol

def computerMove(board):
    number=randint(0,24)
    row=int(number/5)
    col=number
    if col>4:
        col=int(col%5)
    while board[row][col]=="X" or board[row][col]=="O": #computer chooses a random integer between 0 and 24 until the cell is not taken
        number=randint(0,24)
    board[row][col]="O" #change cell to computer symbol ("O")

def checkWinner(board):       
    #check rows
    for row in board:
        if len(set(row))==1: #if there is only one symbol in the board
            return True
    #check columns
    for col in range(5):
        completecol=True
        for row in range(5):
            if board[row][col]!=board[row-1][col]:
                completecol=False
                break
        if completecol:
            return True
    #check diagonal
    if len(set(board[row][row] for row in range(5)))==1:
        return True
    if len(set(board[row][5-row-1] for row in range(5)))==1:
        return True
    return False
        
    
def main():
    board=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]] #initialize board
    turns=0 #turn counter
    print("The board is numbered from 1 to 25 as per the following:")      
    displayBoard(board)
    print("Player starts first. Simply input the number of the cell you want to occupy. Player's move is marked with X. Computer's move is marked with O.")
    play=input("Start? y/n: ")    #if the player chooses y, start game loop
    while play=="y": 
        number=int(input("Which cell would you like to occupy? "))
        while checkIfLegal(number,board)==False: #player chooses a number until it is legal
            number=int(input("Please enter a new cell: "))
            checkIfLegal(number,board)
        if checkIfLegal(number,board)==True: #once number is legal, update board
            updateBoard(number,board,"X")
        number=number-1 
        row=int(number/5)
        col=number
        if col>4:
            col=int(col%5)                
        if checkWinner(board)==True: 
            displayBoard(board)
            print("Congratulations! You won!")
            break
        turns+=1 
        if turns==25: #if 25 turns are taken with no winner, board is full and it is a tie.
            print("Tie game!")
            break
        computerMove(board)
        if checkWinner(board)==True: 
            displayBoard(board)
            print("Too bad. Computer won!")
            break
        turns+=1
        displayBoard(board)
    
        
    
main()
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4QwX.png [python shell]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an infinite loop here:

```
while board[row][col]=="X" or board[row][col]=="O": #computer chooses a random integer between 0 and 24 until the cell is not taken
    number=randint(0,24)
```

You aren't recalculating the values of `row` and `col` from the new value of `number`.  So the loop condition remains unchanged.  Once you hit a case where the loop condition is true, you'll never exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `computerMove()` function you are creating an infinite loop by passing a random integer between 0 and 24 in your `number` variable and then doing nothing with it (it stays unused).
What I tried to do is copy

```
row=int(number/5)
    col=number
    if col>4:
        col=int(col%5)
```

inside the while loop like this:

```
def computerMove(board):
    number = randint(0, 24)
    row = int(number / 5)
    col = number
    if col > 4:
        col = int(col % 5)
    while board[row][col] == "X" or board[row][col] == "O":
        number = randint(0, 24)
        row = int(number / 5)
        col = number
        if col > 4:
            col = int(col % 5)
    board[row][col] = "O"
```

And your programm works like a charm!